# GKMartch.sendData method is obsoleted in iOS 14

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit, data-transfer

I am working on a game that involves gameCenter and by extension sending data with Game Center. Before iOS 14 betas began coming out, the `GKMatch sendData:toPlayers:dataMode:error:` method worked great however, the console is now telling me that this method has been removed.

This would not be a problem but it does not tell me what method to replace it with, and I am unable to find it anywhere in apple's developer documents. If anyone knows of a good replacement function so I can once again send and receive data, and have updated apps, that'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple told me that this issue was recently fixed. Try updating to iOS 14 beta 3 and Xcode 12 beta 3.